# factory_girl: Strange error when creating objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot, rubymine

I get a strange error whenever I call any FactoryGirl create or build method.

In my spec file I have a before-block where I want to create a basic list of users:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Users" do
  before do
    create_list(:user, 3, :confirmed)
    @user = User.first
  end
end
```

This line `create_list` throws the following error:

```
TypeError: nil is not a symbol
./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My only factory file `./spec/factories/user.rb` seems to be loaded.
If I raise an error in the first line this error is thrown when I execute the spec tests.

This is the content of my factory file:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:friend] do
    sequence(:username) { |n| "foo#{n}" }
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation {"#{password}"}
    email { "#{username}@example.com" }
    date_of_birth 20.years.ago

    trait :admin do
      admin true
    end
    trait :game_admin do
       game_admin true
    end
    trait :confirmed do
      confirmed_at Time.now
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Since you do not use `FactoryGirl.create_list(...`, let us know if you have already [mixed the syntax methods into Rspec](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-factories).

Comment: Yes, I load the FactoryGirl DSL in my spec_helper: config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

Comment: And if I leave out all arguments for create_list an exception "Wrong number of arguments" is raised. So it seems the create method is found.

Comment: Some news: I found out that the problem is in friendly_id. My User model returns nil for the call User.primary_key in test environment. Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved.
After digging deeper into the full trace I found that the error was thrown in a part of friendly_id.
friendly_id tried to work with the primary_key of my model User, which (however) returned nil.
And so, User.send(key) throw this error.

I don't know why the primary_key of my model was null suddenly, but after the following rake commands everything is fine now:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
rake db:test:prepare
```